# Can I own and create adhesives trash bags/ trash bags with adhesives for use?

Tags: us20050129335

In reference to the patent: [US20050129335](https://www.google.com/patents/US20050129335)

Does this patent currently limit such an opportunity as to the making or selling adhesive trash bags, if so how can I bypass it or aquire exlusive ownership rights from the present owner? How would I got about arranging such a sale if it deems necessary? Or is it possible to create my own patent upon trash bags with adhesives that would protect a potentially proprietary product? How can I establish exclusive rights to adhesive trash bags for strong competitive advantage purposes, to keep any other adhesive trash bag competition out of such an area or emerging in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. This may be better broken up into several separate questions so that each can be answered separately.

Answer (score 0):

This was a patent application, not a patent. According to Public PAIR, it is abandoned. This means it isn't a patent and isn't going to be. I'm not a lawyer so I'm not sure if it has any hope of being revived.

With regards to your other questions, currently this application doesn't keep you from making and selling adhesive trash bags. This doesn't mean there aren't other patents that might exist so you should do a search. With regards to you being able to patent your own type of adhesive trash bag. What matters is whether your idea is novel and non obvious. The application does represent prior art so you can't patent what was in it or any other patent or application.

Answer (score -1):

> Does this patent currently limit such an opportunity as to the making
>   or selling adhesive trash bags, if so how can I bypass it or aquire
>   exlusive ownership rights from the present owner?

Patent Expired :-  Check USPTO Patent Register called [Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)

Comment: According to PAIR, it was abandoned. It was never a patent so it couldn't have expired.